# Change the color for code embedded in markdown in shinydashboard shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny (shinydashboard) app that contains embedded markdown with a code chunk which displays in red by default.  How can I change the color?

Here is a demo app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    includeMarkdown("demo.md"),

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The markdown file demo.md has this line:

```
This is a `code` example.
```

That word "code" renders with a red font.  I would like to change the color.

I messed around with extra lines in the app:

```
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
        .code {
          color: #000000;
        }
      ')))
```

and

```
tags$style(
  type = 'text/css', 
  '.code {color: black;}'
)
```

without success.

Can somebody tell me what I can add to the markdown or R file to change the color of the embedded code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [shinydashboard documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#css), we can either use an external CSS file or just include them in the UI code. So, your first attempt is quite close but you just need to use the correct CSS selector.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        includeMarkdown("demo.md"),
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
            code {
                color: blue;
            }
        ")))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That was painful.  So close to right....  Thank you so much.